# to give someone the benefit of the doubt

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

This common English idiom means ‘to continue trusting someone despite reservations or misgivings’. How might it be translated into Latin? I can only think of some wordy phrase like alicui confidere certis dumtaxat positis cautionibus. Or, more concisely, dubitanter alicui confidere. But neither equivalent is satisfctory.

Answer (score 6):

I will focus on the "benefit of the doubt" part.
It seems to be a common expression in all Romance languages.

- English: benefit of the doubt
- French: bénéfice du doute
- Italian: beneficio del dubbio
- Spanish: beneficio de la duda

So simply "beneficium dubii" could be a reasonable translation. And it is attested in a few places:

> If we extend the beneficium dubii to those contradictory statements… [Collected Works of C.G. Jung](https://books.google.fr/books?id=1BQ3AgAAQBAJ)

> so hat der Patient das volle Recht das Beneficium dubii… [New Yorker Medizinische Presse](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ofQvAAAAIAAJ)

> I would argue instead that a hermeneutic of the beneficium dubii… [The Politics of Theological Free Speech in the Cappadocian Fathers](https://dukespace.lib.duke.edu/dspace/bitstream/handle/10161/16970/Benedict_duke_0066D_14691.pdf?isAllowed=y&sequence=1)